# Fetch Magento Product Url in a loop

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to fetch the "URL Key" of all products of magento.
Can anyone suggest how to run that loop?

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('url_key');

foreach($collection as $product){

      var_dump($product->getUrlKey()); 
}
```

Comment: He is asking for `url_key` ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 <?php   
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin'); 
    $product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array("eq" => 2))
                ->load();                    

    foreach ($product as $pid)
    {
            echo $pid->getUrlKey().'<br />';


    }   

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();                                        
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
echo $_product->getUrlKey() . '</br>';
}
```